# Wrong function value return

Tags: c++

This shoud return result 21.5 but this return 21 where is mistake please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

float Funkcja(int a)
{
    static_cast<float>(a);
    a += 1.5;
    return a;
}
void main()
{
    float(*pWskazn)(int);
    pWskazn = &Funkcja;
    cout << (pWskazn)(20);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `int main();`  ...

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: `a` is an `int`; you cannot expect it to have a floating point value, no matter what you do on it (hint: casting does not actually change the value of the casted variable).

Comment: if you switched on warnings, you've very probably get one about the static_cast line doing nothing.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answer, which solves your problem as "accepted". That helps people visiting SO in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Your cast has no effect, you need to store it in a variable.

```
float Funkcja(int a)
{
    float f = static_cast<float>(a);
    f += 1.5;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: If you return f instead of a, you'll have better chances of it being 21.5 :-)

Comment: @DanielDaranas of course, I tried to beat the others to the chase and made a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out =)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the result back to `a`, which is `int`. The result of the cast is not used.

Here is how you can fix the function:

```
float Funkcja(int a)
{
    return static_cast<float>(a) + 1.5;
}
```

A cast is an expression, not a declaration. When you do `static_cast<float>(a)`, the compiler calculates the value of the cast, which you can use in further calculations, but the variable itself remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast<float>(a)` does not change the type of `a` to float. It converts the value that `a` holds to a float. As used in the code snippet it then discards the value because it isn't used.

`static_cast<float>(a) + 1.5` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
   static_cast<float>(a);
```

does not make `a` a float. It only makes `a` as a float at that line when it is interpreted.

```
float b = static_cast<float>(a);
b += 1.5;
return b;
```